# How can I review updates before actually upgrading with apt-get in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade, apt-get

Before acutally doing

```
#apt-get upgrade
```

on a Debian server, I'd like to get an overview of the package names about to be updated and what the changes are in those packages.

Recently my root account had mail with such a list. It contained all the packages to be upgraded and a changelog for each package. Now I don't know how I got that mail en thus I don't know how to get it again.

The closest I can get so far is:

```
apt-get -s upgrade
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would first do:

```
apt-get update
```

and then run:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

That should then give you the latest changes and ask you if you will like to perform the changes or not.

Comment: Yes that's correct but not (entirely) what I need. I want a full text with explanation why a new package is being installed, what are the changes, what's the priority, ... .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `aptitude`. You can browse through available security updates and upgradable packages and press `C` to see the changelog (also available in the menu by pressing `Ctrl + t`). It is smart enough to show you the changelog for the latest version. You can do the same with `apt-get changelog <package-name>`, but it doesn't seem to work so well, at least on my system. It's failing for a package (puppet) that works through aptitude, and I don't know if it's possible to specify a list of packages (other than by generating and parsing it).